# Connect to Talend Big Data Server (TAC) from external Java program

Tags: java, talend, bigdata

Requirement:

- Connect to Talend server (TAC) via JDBC/HTTPCLIENT/SOME OTHER SERVICE.
- Read Jobs defined in Talend.
- Extract Job workflow info: Hive job, parallelize operation, etc.
- List all the details of the workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talend Server if you mean as TAC then you can send MetaServlet POST requests from talend execution server to send job to TAC and they will show up.

This can be a regular POST request to TAC metaservlet. I am giving an example of a curl request I made.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"{"actionName":"runTask","authPass":xxxx,"authUser":xxxx,"mode":"can be sychronous or async","taskId":xxxx}"' tacURL
```

Go through the below link and see if that helps.

https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Talend+Administration+Center+MetaServlet+API+documentation

Comment: Hi, Could you please share some piece of code if you have?

Comment: Are you able to connect ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. To find the underlying workflow of Talend, we exported the job and referred the .item xml file to achieve the task. Your solution is quite useful to track jobs at Talend level. However my end goal was to retrieve job workflow so that I can migrate it to a different tool.

Comment: Could you kindly accept my answer. that will be a great help.